# Unable to alias a DataFrame in Pypsark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a simple DataFrame script in Pyspark but am unable to "alias" a dataframe. What am I doing wrong.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf 
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,StructType,StructField,StringType,IntegerType 

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('myDFApp').master('local').getOrCreate() 
sc = spark.sparkContext 

input_data = [('retail', '2017-01-03T13:21:00', 134), 
    ('marketing', '2017-01-03T13:21:00', 100)] 
rdd_schema = StructType([StructField('business', StringType(), True), \ 
    StructField('date', StringType(), True), \
    StructField("US.sales", IntegerType(), True)])

input_df = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, rdd_schema)
print('Count= ', input_df.count())

# this line below works 
df_1 = input_df.select((input_df.business).alias('partnership'))

# this line does not work
df_2 = input_df.alias("s"). \
    where(s.date > "2016-01-03") 

df_2.show()
```

The Error I get is:

```
Count=  2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/opt/inscape/test_dataframe.py", line 22, in <module>
    where(s.date > "2016-01-03")
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The Alias is not the same thing as a variable name. Here, in your example, you're using it as a variable. One suggestion I can give you. Use the same alias as you variable name in your code. it will make it easier.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you post the updated lines of code you are suggesting?

Comment: Just use the same alias as you dataframe name


`
df_2 = input_df.alias("df_2"). \
    where(df_2.date > "2016-01-03") 
`


Because you are using it in your case as a variable. (where(df_2.date > "2016-01-03") )

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work either. I resorted to using df_2 = input_df. \                                                                                                                                                                                         where(input_df.date > "2016-01-03") and it works. I guess can't alias a DF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you alias a dataframe you change the reference name in Spark metadata not the reference variable in Python, in Python the dataframe name still be the `input_df`. You can use the `col` object in order to have access to `s` dataframe. Try the following to fix it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_2 = input_df.alias("s"). \
    where(col("s.date") > "2016-01-03")
```